# Javascript Modification to Allow Alert

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, alert

I have very limited javascript experience and Im trying to modify the script below to show an alert of success or failure after the POST attempt:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("form").submit(function(e) {
                $.post($(this).attr("action"),
                        $(this).serialize(),
                        function(data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
</script>
```

I know it needs to look like this:

```
success: function(){
                    alert("Edit successful");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('failure');
```

but cant figure out how to integrate it without syntax errors.  This script is for performing the POST that the above code would normally perform to allow for this confirmation of success or failure to occur:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Admin", "Home", "POST"))
{
    <div class="well">
        <section>
            <br>
            <span style="font-weight:bold">Text File Destination:&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>
            <input type="text" name="txt_file_dest" value="@ViewBag.one">
            <span style="color:black">&#160;&#160;&#160;Example:</span><span style="color:blue"> \\pathpart1\\pathpart2$\\</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <span style="font-weight:bold">SQL Connection String:</span>
            <input type="text" name="sql_Connection" value="@ViewBag.two">
            <span style="color:black">&#160;&#160;&#160;Example:</span> <span style="color:blue"> Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myusername;Pwd=mypswd</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="document">Save Changes</button>
        </section>
    </div>
}
```

ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Admin(string txt_file_dest, string sql_Connection)
        {
            AdminModel Values = new AdminModel();

            if (txt_file_dest != null)
            {
                Values.SAVEtxtDestination(txt_file_dest);
            }

            if (sql_Connection != null)
            {
                Values.SAVEsqlConnection(sql_Connection);
            }
            ViewBag.one = Values.GetTextPath();
            ViewBag.two = Values.GetSqlConnection();
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post(
    $(this).attr("action"), // url
    $(this).serialize(), // data
    function(data) { //success callback function
        alert("Edit successful");
    }).error(function() {
        alert('failure');
    });
```

That's a shorthand ajax function that you can write as:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $(this).attr("action"),
  data:  $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(data){
    alert("Edit successful");
  },
  error(function() {
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

Comment: I edited the script to use what you provided in your first code sample.  It appears to work but for some reason always returns an error.  I've posted my actionresult code above.  Any ideas as to why it fails?

Comment: Sorry I was already out for the day when you sent the message. Glad you worked it out. You're welcome :)